# Return an entity where entity Id is not equal to any of values in an int array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How can I get EF Core to return an entity where the `Id` is not equal to any of the values in an int array?

I display a bunch of pictures and need to select a picture from the database that's not currently being displayed.

The code I got so far (not much):

```
public async Task<IPicture> GetUniquePicture(int[] existingIds)
{
    IPicture result = null;

    _context.Pictures.Where();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with **`Contains`**

```
_context.Pictures.Where(r => !existingIds.Contains(r.ID));
```

**EDIT**

As Michal mentioned in the comment, if you need single entity to be returned use **`FirstOrDefault`** with **`Contains`**

Comment: check it for null :)

Comment: Note that method needs to return single entity instead of collection.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `FirstOrDefault` method, which accepts predicate to specify filtering. Predicate uses `Contains` method of an array:

```
_context.Pictures.FirstOrDefault(picture => ! existingIds.Contains(picture.ID));
```

Note that, `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if the pedicate filters out all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this checking by using `All`

```
_context.Pictures.Where(picture => existingIds.All(id=> id != picture.ID));
```

and if you just want to return an element and not a collection:

```
_context.Pictures.FirstOrDefault(picture => existingIds.All(id=> id != picture.ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with: (Random is a custom extension method)

```
public async Task<IPicture> GetUniquePicture(int[] existingIds)
{
    var tmp = await _context.Pictures.Where(p => !existingIds.Contains(p.Id)).ToListAsync();

    return tmp.Random().First();
}
```

thanks!